# How to pass on a php variable to a php page for further processing using its object id?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am using a PHP generated link/button to pass on a variable to the referred page and using $_GET[''] to capture the variable.

Following is my anchor tag script:

```
echo "<a href='miniStat.php?pod=<?php echo $acct_currency[0] ?>' class='btn btn-primary'>View Recent Transactions</a>";
```

And this is how I am using $_GET procedure:

```
echo $_GET['pod'];
```

And here is the output from the referred browser window:

https://www.example.com/accts/miniStat.php?pod=%3C?php%20echo%20aed%20?%3E

And the three letters string 'aed' is exactly what I want to capture.  Could someone please have a look at these lines to see what mistake am I making?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: `echo "<a href='miniStat.php?pod={$acct_currency[0]}' class='btn btn-primary'>View Recent Transactions</a>";`?

Comment: @Nick Thanks a lot for the help it did work.

Comment: @MuhammadKhan  you can't have echo echo .... you need to escape your string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks wrong

```php
echo "<a href='miniStat.php?pod=<?php echo $acct_currency[0] ?>' class='btn btn-primary'>View Recent Transactions</a>";
```

I think the right version should be

```php
echo "<a href='miniStat.php?pod=".$acct_currency[0]."' class='btn btn-primary'>View Recent Transactions</a>";
```